# Button to bookmark an image to a WordPress form

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm on a project where I need to create a bookmarking button that sends the link from the bookmarked image on any site to a form on my WordPress site.
exactly like the Pinterest save button.
Can someone guide me? the language to use (javascript I think)...

Comment: Please include some code or what you have tried so far.